# Babel-loader mangles Webpack's source map sources for node_modules

Tags: webpack

Using `babel-loader` with Webpack, if one does not exclude `node_modules`, Webpack's source maps will (incorrectly) use the path listed in each module's own source maps, rather than generating new paths.

For example, I'm using module `a`, which is laid out like the following:

```
node_modules/
--a/
----dist/
------index.js
------index.js.map
----src/
------index.ts
```

Inside that source map there is `"sources":["../src/index.ts"]`, which is reasonable and correct.

However, when Webpack consumes this, `'webpack:///../src/index.ts'` will be one of the `sources` of the source map. This is not a TS project and that entry will disappear if the usage of `a` is commented out, so there is no confusion as to where this entry is coming from.

If I were to add `exclude: /node_modules/` to my `babel-loader` config, the correct source is displayed as `"webpack:///./node_modules/a/dist/index.js"`.

How can I correct this? Using these source maps is rather impossible because they contain relative paths from deep within a module. I have no way of knowing on larger project with dozens of modules what `../src/index.ts` is actually referring to.

Webpack config:

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = function() {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.m?[jt]sx?$/,
                    //exclude: /node_modules/,  // Uncommenting "fixes" the sources
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            ]
        },
        mode: 'production',
        devtool: 'source-map',

        output: {
            filename: 'ssr-bundle.js',
            path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        externals: {
            preact: 'preact'
        },
        target: 'node',
    }
}
```

Example entry point to use as reproduction material:

```js
import { h } from 'preact';
import { computed, signal } from '@preact/signals';

const currentState = signal('idle');
const isFormEnabled = computed(() => currentState.value !== 'loading');

export default function App() {
    return h('form', {}, [
        h('input', { type: 'text', disabled: !isFormEnabled.value })
    ]);
}
```

(`@preact/signals` is `a` from the above example. It's not important and can be swapped out with anything.)

```
"@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
"webpack": "^5.74.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some annoying experiences with source map from `node_modules` previously . Then I came up with a best solution is to use a community [`source-map-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/source-map-loader/) rather than just only use the built-in source map after having done some experiments without a desire results. In short, you might find it set up properly with this setup:

```js
{
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Strange, I'm essentially adding a loader in order to get Webpack to ignore existing source maps and point to built files. Had to combine it with `babel-loader` (i.e., `use: ['babel-loader', 'source-map-loader']`) to get things to work correctly but sure enough they do. Thanks!